# Trace back columns in calculated measures

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

How do I trace back the actual columns used/joined in calculated measure? THe reason I am asking this question is, I am trying to write the equivalent TSQL query to verify the result with that of calculated measure. 
So far, my approach has been a look up into the measure properties and find the table/view and the column name used. The joining column has been a difficult part (let s say it impossible for me), because the DSV looks very messy and is hard to follow the lines.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no hope of contacting the person who created the cube, or currently maintains it? If you are not familiar with the data warehouse the cube comes from, I can see why this would feel like a nightmare. There may be various procs/jobs which load data in.

One on-going problem in my last job was a customer upset that the cube totals did not match with the figures from other places in our web application. Each week there would be a debate between the OLAP team and the web team, to decide which value ws "right" and how we could explain the difference!

Comment: exactly...but before I could argue, I just wanted to make sure I have not missed anything. Since this is the first time I am into cube, I dont wanna take chances.